# Is there any point in using the warning flags with GCC when just linking object files?

Tags: gcc

If I just want to link some object files, like:

```
gcc a.o b.o c.o -o program
```

is there any point in using the following flags with it:

```
gcc a.o b.o c.o -o program -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror
```

Do they make any difference?

Comment: Succinctly, no, they don't make a difference, but they don't do any harm, either.  At the command line with you typing, you may omit them.  In a makefile, you should probably keep them (via `${CFLAGS}`) just in case a source file gets listed in the link line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, actually I need it for a makefile so thanks

Comment: Use `${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}` to link your programs.  `CFLAGS` will include the warnings etc. `LDFLAGS` will specify library locations and other library-related controls; `LDLIBS` lists the libraries to be linked. Note that the libraries are after the object files; that's important. Don't fret about it — simply do it. `OBJECTS` is the list of object files to be linked: `OBJECTS = a.o b.o c.o` in your example. You'd have a rule `program: ${OBJECTS}` and the command lline shown earlier. GNU Make might have a special variable notation for `${OBJECTS}` in the command.

Comment: You're entirely at liberty to use `$(CFLAGS)` where I used `${CFLAGS}`; both notations are recognized by Make.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}` vs `${CC} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS}` - Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes, the order matters.  I said so (_Note that the libraries are after the object files; that's important._) and I meant what said.  You could but LDFLAGS anywhere on the command line before LDLIBS, but the object files must precede the libraries for reliable cross-platform linking.  On a given platform, you may get away with tinkering with the order, but the next upgrade, or a change to a new platform, stands a decent chance of breaking your code if you put libraries ahead of object files.

Comment: It should make a bigger difference if you use `-flto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer to allow for closure.*</sup>

> Is there any point in including the warning flags when merely linking object files?

Succinctly, no, they don't make a difference, but they don't do any harm, either. At the command line with you typing, you may omit them. In a makefile, you should probably keep them (via `${CFLAGS}`) just in case a source file gets listed in the link line.

Incidentally, the `-g` flag is often important for making debuggable executables. It is needed in both the object-file compilation and the linking command line, but is usually embedded in the `CFLAGS` value.  This is one of the important reasons for including the `CFLAGS` in with the linking operation.  Other linking flags can be misplaced (the `-g` flag is not really misplaced) in the CFLAGS; by using it, you protect yourself from inadvertent errors.

> Well, actually I need it for a makefile

Use this command sequence to link your programs:

```
${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

CFLAGS will include the warnings etc. LDFLAGS will specify library locations and other library-related controls; LDLIBS lists the libraries to be linked. Note that the libraries are after the object files; that's important. Don't fret about it — simply do it. OBJECTS is the list of object files to be linked. In your example:

```
OBJECTS = a.o b.o c.o
```

You'd have a rule:

```
program: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

GNU Make might have a special variable notation for `${OBJECTS}` in the command.

You're entirely at liberty to use `$(CFLAGS)` where I used `${CFLAGS}`; both notations are recognized by Make.

> ```
> ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
> ```
>
> vs
>
> ```
> ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS}
> ```
>
> Does the order matter?

Yes, the order matters. I said so (*Note that the libraries are after the object files; that's important*) and I meant what said. You could but LDFLAGS anywhere on the command line before LDLIBS, but the object files must precede the libraries for reliable cross-platform linking. On a given platform, you may get away with tinkering with the order, but the next upgrade, or a change to a new platform, stands a decent chance of breaking your code if you put libraries ahead of object files.

Comment: Thanks! What I really wanted to ask earlier is if `${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}` vs `${CC} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} -o $@ ${CFLAGS}`  matters; but I copied it incorrectly, which led to an interesting answer.

Comment: The position of the CFLAGS generally doesn't matter, but it is safer to put the options earlier.  The order of options related to linking etc certainly can matter, and if CFLAGS ends up containing an order-dependent link-related flag, putting it at the end might make a difference.